# Ajax call successfull but populating data as undefined from web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I cannot figure out why my ajax calls keeps displaying undefined for just this call but in all my other codes it works fine.

Here's what I am getting:

[image]

Here's what I get when I search by ID:

[image]

here is my code for my ajax:

```
$("#btnGetTaxByBL").click(function () {
            var strURL = "https://localhost:44395/api/ServiceDeed/GetByBlockNLot/" + blockNo + "/" + lotNo;

            $("#display").html("");
            $("#msg").html("");
            $("#update").html("");
            $("#updateResult").html("");

            console.log("btnGetTaxByBL clicked");

            var blockNo = $("#txtBlockNo").val();
            var lotNo = $("#txtLotNo").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: strURL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var owner = data;

                    $("#display").html("<hr><p>".concat("HomeOwnerID: ", owner.HomeOwnerID,
                        "<br>FirstName: ", owner.FirstName, "<br>LastName: ", owner.LastName,
                        "<br>Address: ", owner.Address, "<br>City: ", owner.City,
                        "<br>State: ", owner.State, "<br>ZipCode: ", owner.ZipCode,
                        "<br>Telephone Number: ", owner.TelNo, "<br>Email: ", owner.Email,
                        "<br>Block Number: ", owner.BlockNo, "<br>Lot Number: ", owner.LotNo,
                        "<br>Date of Sale: ", owner.SaleDate, "<br>Sale Price: $", owner.SalePrice,
                        "<br>Sold Status: ", owner.IsSold, "<br>Accessed Value: ", owner.AccessedVal,
                        "<br>Land Value: ", owner.LandVal, "<br>Additional Value: ", owner.AdditionalVal,
                        "<br>Tax Rate: ", owner.TaxRate, "<br>Tax Per Year: ", owner.TaxPerYear,
                        "<br>Real Estate Tax: ", owner.RealEstateTax));

                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Error: " + req.responseText + " | " + status + " | " + error);
                }
            }); //end of ajax method
        }); // end of btnGetTaxByBL click event
```

Here is the code for my controller:

```
[HttpGet("GetByBlockNLot/{block}/{lot}")]
    public List<HomeTax> GetByBlockNLot(int block, int lot)
    {
        List<HomeTax> homeTaxList = new List<HomeTax>();
        DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
        String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM HomeOwnership_T INNER JOIN TaxInfo_T ON HomeOwnership_T.HomeOwnerID=TaxInfo_T.HomeOwnerID WHERE BlockNo =" + block + " AND LotNo =" + lot;
        int count = 0;

        objDB.GetDataSet(strSQL, out count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            HomeTax objOwner = new HomeTax();
            objOwner.HomeOwnerID = (int)objDB.GetField("HomeOwnerID", i);
            objOwner.FirstName = (string)objDB.GetField("FirstName", i);
            objOwner.LastName = (string)objDB.GetField("LastName", i);
            objOwner.Address = (string)objDB.GetField("Address", i);
            objOwner.City = (string)objDB.GetField("City", i);
            objOwner.State = (string)objDB.GetField("State", i);
            objOwner.ZipCode = (string)objDB.GetField("ZipCode", i);
            objOwner.TelNo = (string)objDB.GetField("TelNo", i);
            objOwner.Email = (string)objDB.GetField("Email", i);
            objOwner.BlockNo = (int)objDB.GetField("BlockNo", i);
            objOwner.LotNo = (int)objDB.GetField("LotNo", i);
            objOwner.SaleDate = (DateTime)objDB.GetField("SaleDate", i);
            objOwner.SalePrice = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("SalePrice", i);
            objOwner.IsSold = (string)objDB.GetField("IsSold", i);
            objOwner.AccessedVal = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("AccessedVal", i);
            objOwner.LandVal = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("LandVal", i);
            objOwner.AdditionalVal = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("AdditionalVal", i);
            objOwner.TaxRate = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("TaxRate", i);
            objOwner.TaxPerYear = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("TaxPerYear", i);
            objOwner.RealEstateTax = (Decimal)objDB.GetField("RealEstateTax", i);

            homeTaxList.Add(objOwner);
        }
        return homeTaxList;
    }
```

Comment: debugging step 1 - `console.log(data)` - is it what you expected?

Comment: my array is empty? length of 0

Comment: well ... there you go `objDB.GetDataSet(strSQL, out count);` results in no data

Comment: and if the request returns an array, then you're not using it correctly anyway

Comment: Have you looked in your browser console for errors? There should be several

Answer (score 1):

Your API return a list, so you should add a “for” statement to display the list of object, you can’t use the “owner” variable as object because is an Array of objects.

Comment: that's because there is no data - the issue is likely to be on the server side

Comment: there is actual data because when i run it thru the url, data displays. so i know it is working. i just don't know why it is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Here is your issue

You are using `blockNo` and  `lotNo` in `strURL` before they have been assigned a value

```
$("#btnGetTaxByBL").click(function () {
    var strURL = "https://localhost:44395/api/ServiceDeed/GetByBlockNLot/" + blockNo + "/" + lotNo;
    // at this point, blockNo and lotNo are "undefined
        $("#display").html("");
        $("#msg").html("");
        $("#update").html("");
        $("#updateResult").html("");

        console.log("btnGetTaxByBL clicked");

        var blockNo = $("#txtBlockNo").val();
        var lotNo = $("#txtLotNo").val();
```

simply change the code to get `blockNo` and `lotNo` BEFORE using them in `strUrl` will fix the first issue

```
$("#btnGetTaxByBL").click(function () {
    var blockNo = $("#txtBlockNo").val();
    var lotNo = $("#txtLotNo").val();
    var strURL = "https://localhost:44395/api/ServiceDeed/GetByBlockNLot/" + blockNo + "/" + lotNo;
    // now you are passing values rather than undefined
    $("#display").html("");
    $("#msg").html("");
    $("#update").html("");
    $("#updateResult").html("");

    console.log("btnGetTaxByBL clicked");
```

The next issue is, that the result is a list (which will, by the looks of it, be sent as an Array) - but you are not using the response as an array

By changing

```
success: function (data) {
    var owner = data;
    $("#display").html( ... rest of your code
```

to

```
success: function (data) {
    var owner = data[0];
    $("#display").html( ... rest of your code
```

i.e. access the FIRST result in the received array, you will now display data as required

If you expect an array, i.e. more than one record, then your code will need to change significantly, because you'll need to iterate through the data and output multiple records

perhaps something like

```
success: function (data) {
    var owner = data;
    var html = data.map(function(owner) {
        return "<hr><p>".concat("HomeOwnerID: ", owner.HomeOwnerID,
        "<br>FirstName: ", owner.FirstName, "<br>LastName: ", owner.LastName,
        "<br>Address: ", owner.Address, "<br>City: ", owner.City,
        "<br>State: ", owner.State, "<br>ZipCode: ", owner.ZipCode,
        "<br>Telephone Number: ", owner.TelNo, "<br>Email: ", owner.Email,
        "<br>Block Number: ", owner.BlockNo, "<br>Lot Number: ", owner.LotNo,
        "<br>Date of Sale: ", owner.SaleDate, "<br>Sale Price: $", owner.SalePrice,
        "<br>Sold Status: ", owner.IsSold, "<br>Accessed Value: ", owner.AccessedVal,
        "<br>Land Value: ", owner.LandVal, "<br>Additional Value: ", owner.AdditionalVal,
        "<br>Tax Rate: ", owner.TaxRate, "<br>Tax Per Year: ", owner.TaxPerYear,
        "<br>Real Estate Tax: ", owner.RealEstateTax);
    }).join('');
    $("#display").html(html);
},
```

Comment: it still gets me undefined but now my console shows the actual data

Comment: it's an array - let me flesh out the answer

Comment: @Phil - I did so in comments - fleshing out the answer now